# Print a subpart of main function in json

Tags: arrays, json, http

Below is the output of my http request and now I want to print only message from messages, not the severity .How I can achieve that here?

```
    {"messages": [
    {
        "message": "Data Source 'TestDataSource' is in a state incompatible with this operation at server 'manaed_server_4'.",
        "severity": "FAILURE"
    },
    {
        "message": "Data Source 'TestDataSource' is in a state incompatible with this operation at server 'managed_server_3'.",
        "severity": "FAILURE"
    }
]}
```

I know how print a single message i.e. `$.messages[0].message`, but how can I print all message in one go?

Comment: Show a bit more of the code that currently does the printing.

Comment: Currently I'm using `$.messages` , which prints everything inside messages. Now I just want only message part not the severity.

Comment: Assume I have no idea what "print" means. Print where? How? What is `$` ? Usually `$` means jQuery but obviously that's not the case here. To create a useful answer, you need to show more context.